# Self-hosted webfonts not being cached by Google CDN for AMP pages

Tags: amp-html

My company has recently started experimenting with AMP pages for one of our sites. This process has worked great, and we are seeing Google index our pages for use in the AMP carousel: [Mobile Google Search result for PennLive.com](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&site=&source=hp&ei=M20rV8C1J4O6-AGZi5uACw&q=pennlive&oq=pennlive&gs_l=mobile-gws-hp.3..0i131j0j0i131j0j5.4116.5047.0.5228.10.10.0.1.1.0.257.1482.0j5j3.8.0....0...1c.1.64.mobile-gws-hp..4.5.716.0..0i3j0i131i46j46i131.NlyuZ1J7c3M).

However, our font assets are returning as 404 in the Google carousel, despite them working on our AMP pages directly.

`https://cdn.ampproject.org/r/www.pennlive.com/static/common/fonts/v1/benton-sans-medium/448c4642-c106-472f-9c6a-a4d7b5347b03-3.woff` returns `404`

whereas:

`http://www.pennlive.com/static/common/fonts/v1/benton-sans-medium/448c4642-c106-472f-9c6a-a4d7b5347b03-3.woff` returns `200`

In the amphtml docs, it says that self hosted fonts must be served via http or https, which is what we are doing for our pages, and the AMP pages are obviously validating.

*Why are these fonts not returning 200 when inside the Google AMP carousel?*

**Example page: http://www.pennlive.com/articles/18505993/penn_state_commit_damion_barbe.amp**

**https://www.google.com/amp/www.pennlive.com/articles/18505993/penn_state_commit_damion_barbe.amp#development=1**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server is returning an invalid content-type for the .woff font file.

```
$ curl -I http://www.pennlive.com/static/common/fonts/v1/benton-sans-medium/448c4642-c106-472f-9c6a-a4d7b5347b03-3.woff

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 20 May 2016 17:27:48 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 18 May 2016 15:03:07 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Expires: Fri, 27 May 2016 17:27:48 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
X-Varnish: 198714588
Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
X-ADI-VCache: MISS
Content-Length: 54040
Connection: keep-alive
```

Note `Content-Type: text/plain;`

I think you want `application/x-font-woff` or `font/woff`

Comment: I'm going to fix this issue and see if the fonts show up. I'll accept this answer if this works.

Comment: this solution worked for me. The fonts are returning correct type and now they are showing up in the carousel. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see your `AMP` page; otherwise am trying to infer what might be happening.

Had a similar problem with Font Awesome fonts. Finally discovered this approach:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet" 
  integrity="sha256-MfvZlkHCEqatNoGiOXveE8FIwMzZg4W85qfrfIFBfYc= sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" 
  crossorigin="anonymous"
>
```

I see that [benton-sans-medium](http://www.webtype.com/font/benton-sans-medium/) may be a font that you have licensed. If they will serve the font to you, the approach above might be useful.

Comment: I have added a sample page for you to take a look at. Both the Google CDN and hosted versions are there.

Comment: Not seeing any font problems. When using Chrome Development Tools, the error messages I see relate to `"[amp-analytics.Transport]" "Failed to send image request"` Something is happening with `richmetrics.com`; perhaps `pageviewWidth`. Consider testing with a subset of `analytics`.

Comment: Jay. Those are normal errors, not effecting the AMP validation. If you took a look at the second link, which is of the Google carousel, you will see all the fonts are returning 404s. The non-Google carousel page is not having issues.

Comment: Yea, I did look at that link. But it's not an `AMP` doc; it's a JavaScript doc. Click it yourself. It does point to the first link, which is the one I inspected. True, the first link is AMP valid. The only issue I could see was reported above. Is there another link that you intended to provided?

Comment: Oh yes. I see that now. That was unintended. The only way to view this issue is via the AMP Carousel in Google Search results. Try simulating mobile on Chrome and searching google.com for "pennlive". The articles in the carousel are the ones with the issue.

Comment: If you look at the javascript console whilst looking at the cached page in Google's AMP cache: https://cdn.ampproject.org/c/www.pennlive.com/articles/18505993/penn_state_commit_damion_barbe.amp#development=1 you can see the errors.

Comment: Will look this end-of-day and BBTY.

Comment: @ade Yes. I am aware of the console errors. The ones I care about specifically are the 404 errors regarding the webfonts. As I stated in the question, "Why are these fonts not returning 200 when inside the Google AMP carousel?".

Comment: @JayGray, did you ever get a chance to evaluate this?

Comment: OK, I see the condition you are describing. Have seen similar results using sample Google AMP documents. One reason may be that the Benton font is not on a Google white list. Try this. Rather than using a relative address for the font - based on your 'site address' - use an absolute URL. Perhaps the CDN is not referencing this properly: `src:url('/r/www.pennlive`